# How to truncate periodindex according to start date and end date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-range

I need to get the weekly periods between these two dates:

```
start_date = '2020-11-12'
end_date = '2020-12-21'
```

So I have thought of using:

```
pd.period_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='W')
```

And the output is:

```
PeriodIndex(['2020-11-09/2020-11-15', '2020-11-16/2020-11-22',
             '2020-11-23/2020-11-29', '2020-11-30/2020-12-06',
             '2020-12-07/2020-12-13', '2020-12-14/2020-12-20',
             '2020-12-21/2020-12-27'],
            dtype='period[W-SUN]', freq='W-SUN')
```

The problem is that as seen in the output, the periods in the first and last position include days that are outside *start_date* and *end_date*. How can I make sure that those days are not included in the periods?

Comment: How should looks expected ouput? Because `W-SUN` means periods between weeks by calendar, so `'2020-11-09/2020-11-15'` is week with `start_date=start_date` and similar end_date. So ouput is expected.

Comment: If need starting and ending different datetimes like first and end day per weeks then it is not week periods.

Comment: I need the first period to be  `'2020-11-12/2020-11-15'`.

Comment: Each period need 7 days, so not possible.